# Keras - TypeError: 'NoneType' object cannot be interpreted as an index

Tags: python, keras

I have the following code snippet:

```
model = load_model('model.h5')

optimizer = optimizers.Adam(lr=0.0001)

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(test_directory):
    sortedFiles = sorted(files, key=lambda x:int(x.split('.')[0]))
    for file in sortedFiles[0:]:
        img = cv2.imread(root + '/' + file)
        test_images.append(img)

test_images = np.array(test_images)
test_images = test_images.reshape((None,512,512,3))
```

Why am I getting:

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object cannot be interpreted as an index
```

at:

```
test_images = test_images.reshape((None,512,512,3))
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

While `keras` sometimes has `None` in data shapes, Numpy does not. If you want to have a dimension of variable size, you put `-1` instead. Change your last line to:

```
test_images = test_images.reshape((-1,512,512,3))
```

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply. Yes, I in fact tried this solution, but got this error: ValueError: Error when checking : expected input_1 to have shape (None, 512, 512, 1) but got array with shape (47, 512, 512, 3)

Comment: @Simplicity It seems your model expects grayscale images (e.g. one channel), whereas you are feeding it RGB images (e.g. three channels).

Answer (score 0):

The `None` used in data shapes in `Keras` refers to the possibility that the input can have variable dimension size. It can vary depending on how many examples you give for training.
This can be defined in the input layer of your Functional Keras model, such as :

```
inputs = Input(shape=(512,512,3,))

inputs
>> <tf.Tensor 'input_1:0' shape=(None, 512, 512, 3) dtype=float32>
```

In contrast, the input data to your model (test_images in your case) should have a fixed size defined by the (Batch_size, image_shape) where the Batch_size can vary from an input instance to another.

For instance, if you have 1000 samples data, you should get something like that:

```
test_images.shape
>> (1000, 512, 512, 3)
```